# Android: how to get notification importance

Tags: android, notifications

I wrote a simple service.
All that it does is listen to ALL notifications and display small window to show it for each (duplicating system notify window).
I use

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(final StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    if (???) { showSmallWindow(sbn);}
}
```

But my app shows small window for ALL notifications, so it is not clever.

I want to read importance (priority) of each notification and decide if to show small window or not.

How I can get IMPORTANCE here, please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need to know importance, please notice!
`isOngoing()`  - all that need.